# I have python django backend for webscarpping project. As input i give the website name and it scrapes data. But it takes too long time. How to scale?

Tags: django, apache-spark, web, web-crawler, horizontal-scaling

In my project for 10 websites on 20000 records. It takes too much time to scrape. I have introduced multi-threading for the same. But still i see lot of time consumption. Is there a way i can scale my servers and make it faster ? Currently using multi-threading. But want to know how to scale servers and resolve issue.

Comment: Without further details about your current architecture it's difficult to figure out a proper solution, but you could go with a serverless cloud approach, as AWS Lambda, which scales as long as you want, or maybe implement a queue system like RabbitMQ with several workers. In the case you only have one server, you may try asyncio or, if the tasks are CPU bound, multiprocessing.